# fast prototyping REST rest interface?

Tags: rest

Scenario:

1. I have REST API specification, something like swagger, raml, or apiary
2. I have front-end already prototyped which can handle CRUDs
3. Now I need to prototype back-end, from specification in 1. to simulate CRUDs and some simple business logic

what would be the best solution for this? I may write small routes in `flask` or `node.js` real quick, but are there solutions specialized for writing REST API prototype server? I think I can code in python, node.js, and haskell